# lftp miror does not remove extra files

Tags: linux, sync, mirroring, lftp

I'm trying to mirror remote ftp to local dir:

```
lftp -u 'user','pass' -e 'mirror -vv ./wp-content ./ && ex' sftp://x.x.x.x -p 22
Old file `cache/index-https-mobile.html' is not removed
Old directory `cache/w-r' is not removed
```

The local user is root.

Why the old files and directories are not removed locally? How can I fix it?